# Hive on Spark: Failed to create spark client

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to make Hive 2.1.1 on Spark 2.1.0 work on a single instance. I'm not sure that's the right approach. Currently I only have one instance so I can't build a cluster.

When I run any insert query in hive, I get the error:

```
hive> insert into mcus (id, name) values (1, 'ARM');
Query ID = server_20170223121333_416506b4-13ba-45a4-a0a2-8417b187e8cc
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

I'm afraid that I didn't configure correctly since I couldn't find any Spark logs under `hdfs dfs -ls /spark/eventlog`. Here's part of my hive-site.xml which is related to Spark and Yarn:

```
<property>
     <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
     <value>/tmp/hive-staging</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion</name>
     <value>more</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
     <value>spark</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.master</name>
     <value>spark://ThinkPad-W550s-Lab:7077</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.eventLog.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/spark/eventlog</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
     <value>2g</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.serializer</name>
     <value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.home</name>
     <value>/home/server/spark</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>spark.yarn.jar</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/spark-jars/*</value>
 </property>
```

1) Since I didn't configure the `fs.default.name` value in hadoop, could I just use `hdfs://localhost:8020` as the file system path in the config file or change the port to 9000 (I get the same error when I change 8020 to 9000)?

[image]

2) I start spark by `start-master.sh` and `start-slave.sh spark://ThinkPad-W550s-Lab:7077`, is it correct?

<s>3) According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589062/failed-to-create-spark-client-hive-on-spark-exception), how could I check the value of `Spark Executor Memory + Overhead` in order to set the values of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`?</s>

The values of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` are much greater than `spark.executor.memory`.

4) How could I fix the `Failed to create spark client` error?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For your 3rd question, you can find the values of yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb  properites in yarn-default.xml file. Alternatively, If you have access to yarn resource manager you can find the values under Tools-> Configuration(xml)

Comment: Thanks I find them!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the **spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.JAVA_HOME** property was a problem.

fix...

```
  <property>
    <name>spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME</name>
    <value>${HADOOP CLUSTER JDK PATH}</value>
    <description>Must be hadoop cluster jdk PATH.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.JAVA_HOME</name>
      <value>${HADOOP CLUSTER JDK PATH}</value>
      <description>Must be hadoop cluster jdk PATH.</description>
  </property>
```